# Origine du suffixe -bole dans différents mots

Tags: étymologie, suffixes, grec

J'ai remarqué que le suffixe -bole est utilisé dans un certain nombre de mots, de sens pourtant parfois éloignés:

> symbole, hyperbole, métabolisme...

Pourtant après avoir effectué des recherches, il s'est avéré que le suffixe -bole vient du grec ancien **bolê** qui signifie "jeter".
Comment expliquer la relation entre l'action de jeter et le sens de tous ces mots ?

Answer (score 1):

Cette relation n'est pas spécifique au français mais existait déjà dans les mots latins et avant eux grecs dont ils sont issus :

Voici ce qu'en dit le TLFi

> [Symbole](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/symbole) :  Empr. au lat.symbolum « pièce justificative d'identité, signe de reconnaissance » lat. chrét. « symbole de la foi, le symbole des apôtres, profession de foi au baptême; signe allégorique, figure; écot, festin par écot », lui-même empr. au gr. σ υ ́ μ β ο λ ο ν « signe de reconnaissance (objet coupé en deux, dont deux personnes conservaient chacune la moitié), jeton; signe d'une convention, signe de ralliement; emblème, symbole; convention », dér. de σ υ μ β α ́ λ λ ω trans. « jeter ensemble, mettre ensemble, réunir » intrans. « se rencontrer avec (quelqu'un) »
>
> [Hyperbole](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/hyperbole) : Empr. au lat.hyperbole, gr. υ ̔ π ε ρ ϐ ο λ η ́ terme de rhét., attesté également en gr. comme terme de math. au sens de « section conique », dér. de υ ̔ π ε ρ ϐ α ́ λ λ ω « lancer par-dessus ou au-delà », « dépasser », « surpasser », formé de υ ̔ π ε ́ ρ « au-dessus, sur » et β α ́ λ λ ω « jeter ».
>
> Métabolique ([métabole](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/m%C3%A9tabole)) : Empr. au lat. de l'époque impériale metabola, metabole «id.» (comme terme de rhét. et de mus. chez Quintilien; cf. TLL), lui-même empr. au gr. μ ε τ α β ο λ η ́ «changement», de μ ε τ α β α ́ λ λ ε ι ν «retourner, changer, transformer», de μ ε τ α ́ v. méta- et de β α ́ λ λ ε ι ν «lancer, jeter», v. aussi baller.

Comment: Merci il faut ajouter διάβολος, le diable qui divise

Comment: On pourrait aussi ajouter "parabole" avec ses deux sens qui proviennent tous deux de grec et dont l'un a un lien évident avec le fait de jeter (trajectoire d'un objet qu'on lance), pour l'autre, c'est moins évident.